# Fitting bimodal gaussian distribution with some parameters fixed

Tags: python, scipy, statistics, distribution

**Problem:** I want to fit empirical data to a bimodal normal distribution from which I know from the physical context the distance of the peaks (fixed) and also that both peaks must have the same standard deviation.

I was trying to create an own distribution with [`scipy.stats.rv_continous`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rv_continuous.html#scipy.stats.rv_continuous) (see code below), but the parameters are always fitted to 1. Does someone understand what's going on, or can point me to a different approach to solve the problem?

**Details:** I avoided the `loc`and `scale` parameters and implemented them as `m`and `s` directly into the `_pdf`-method since the peak distance `delta` shall not be affected by `scale`. To compensate that, I fixed them to `floc=0` and `fscale=1` in the `fit`-method and actually want fit-parameters for `m`, `s` and the weights of the peaks `w`

What I expect in the sample data is a distribution with peaks around `x=-450` and `x=450` (=> `m=0`). The stdev `s` should be around 100 or 200, but not 1.0, and the weight `w`should be approx. 0.5

```
from __future__ import division
from scipy.stats import rv_continuous
import numpy as np


class norm2_gen(rv_continuous):
    def _argcheck(self, *args):
        return True

    def _pdf(self, x, m, s, w, delta):
        return np.exp(-(x-m+delta/2)**2 / (2. * s**2)) / np.sqrt(2. * np.pi * s**2) * w + \
               np.exp(-(x-m-delta/2)**2 / (2. * s**2)) / np.sqrt(2. * np.pi * s**2) * (1 - w)


norm2 = norm2_gen(name='norm2')

data = [487.0, -325.5, -159.0, 326.5, 538.0, 552.0, 563.0, -156.0, 545.5, 341.0, 530.0, -156.0, 473.0, 328.0, -319.5, -287.0, -294.5, 153.5, -512.0, 386.0, -129.0, -432.5, -382.0, -346.5, 349.0, 391.0, 299.0, 364.0, -283.0, 562.5, -42.0, 214.0, -389.0, 42.5, 259.5, -302.5, 330.5, -338.0, 508.5, 319.5, -356.5, 421.5, 543.0]

m, s, w, delta, loc, scale = norm2.fit(data, fdelta=900, floc=0, fscale=1)
print m, s, w, delta, loc, scale

>>> 1.0 1.0 1.0 900 0 1
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to get your distribution to fit the data after making a couple tweaks:

- Using `w` as you did, you have an implied constraint that 0 <= `w` <= 1.  The solver used by the `fit()` method isn't aware of this constraint, so `w` could end up with unreasonable values.  One way to handle this type of constraint is to allow `w` to be an arbitrary real value, but in the formula for the PDF, convert `w` to a fraction `phi` between 0 and 1 using `phi = 0.5 + arctan(w)/pi`.
- The generic `fit()` method uses a numerical optimization routine to find the maximum likelihood estimate.  Like most such routines, it needs a starting point for the optimization.  The default starting point is all 1s, but this doesn't always work well.  You can choose a different starting point by providing the values as positional arguments to `fit()` after the data.  The values that I used in the script worked; I didn't explore how sensitive the results were to these starting values.

I did two estimations.  In the first, I let `delta` be a free parameter, and in the second, I fixed `delta` at 900.

The script below generates the following plot:

[image: plot]

Here's the script:

```
from __future__ import division
from scipy.stats import rv_continuous
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


class norm2_gen(rv_continuous):
    def _argcheck(self, *args):
        return True

    def _pdf(self, x, m, s, w, delta):
        phi = 0.5 + np.arctan(w)/np.pi
        return np.exp(-(x-m+delta/2)**2 / (2. * s**2)) / np.sqrt(2. * np.pi * s**2) * phi + \
               np.exp(-(x-m-delta/2)**2 / (2. * s**2)) / np.sqrt(2. * np.pi * s**2) * (1 - phi)

norm2 = norm2_gen(name='norm2')


data = [487.0, -325.5, -159.0, 326.5, 538.0, 552.0, 563.0, -156.0, 545.5,
        341.0, 530.0, -156.0, 473.0, 328.0, -319.5, -287.0, -294.5, 153.5,
        -512.0, 386.0, -129.0, -432.5, -382.0, -346.5, 349.0, 391.0, 299.0,
        364.0, -283.0, 562.5, -42.0, 214.0, -389.0, 42.5, 259.5, -302.5,
        330.5, -338.0, 508.5, 319.5, -356.5, 421.5, 543.0]

# In the fit method, the positional arguments after data are the initial
# guesses that are passed to the optimization routine that computes the MLE.
# First let's see what we get if delta is not fixed.
m, s, w, delta, loc, scale = norm2.fit(data, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 900.0, floc=0, fscale=1)

# Fit the disribution with delta fixed.
fdelta = 900
m1, s1, w1, delta1, loc, scale = norm2.fit(data, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, fdelta=fdelta, floc=0, fscale=1)

plt.hist(data, bins=12, normed=True, color='c', alpha=0.65)
q = np.linspace(-800, 800, 1000)
p = norm2.pdf(q, m, s, w, delta)
p1 = norm2.pdf(q, m1, s1, w1, fdelta)
plt.plot(q, p, 'k', linewidth=2.5, label='delta=%6.2f (fit)' % delta)
plt.plot(q, p1, 'k--', linewidth=2.5, label='delta=%6.2f (fixed)' % fdelta)
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

Comment: That's it. The weight-transformation solved the issue. Thank you!